# IOptionsWritable.Update() Not writing to json file

Tags: c#, .net

So I have this Windows Forms like program with a Configuration tab configured like this:

**Program.cs**

```
// ...
using IOptionsWriter;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // ...
        var builder = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                // ...
                services.AddSingleton<FormMain>();
                services.AddSingleton<ISomePresenter, SomePresenter>();
                services.AddSingleton<IFormConfiguration, FormConfiguration>();
                // ...
                services.Configure<SomeSectionClass>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("SomeSection"));
                services.ConfigureWritable<SomeSectionClass>("SomeSection");
            }).ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builderConfig) =>
            {
                builderConfig.SetBasePath(context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath);
                builderConfig.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
            });

        var host = builder.Build();

        using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var mainForm = services.GetRequiredSerivce<MainForm>();
        Application.Run(mainForm);
    }
}
```

**SomeSectionClass.cs**

```
public class SomeSectionClass
{
        public string SomeField { get; set; }
}
```

**SomePresenter.cs**

```
// ...
using IOptionsWriter;

public class SomePresenter : ISomePresenter
{
        public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
        private IOptionsWritable<SomeSectionClass> _someWritableOptions;

        public SomePresenter(
            IOptionsWritable<SomeSectionClass> someWritableOptions
            )
        {
                _someWritableOptions = someWritableOptions;
                // ...
                SomeEvent += OnSomeEvent
        }

        private void OnSomeEvent(object sender, SomeArgs args)
        {
                _someWritableOptions.Update(op => op.SomeField = args.SomeValue);
        }
        // ...
}
```

**FormConfiguration.cs** (the main difference is that it extends the Form class and is partial with its Designer)

```
// ...
using IOptionsWriter;

public sealed partial class FormConfiguration : Form, IFormConfiguration
{
        private IOptionsWritable<SomeSectionClass> _someWritableOptions;

        public FormConfiguration(
            IOptionsWritable<SomeSectionClass> someWritableOptions,
            )
        {
                _someWritableOptions = someWritableOptions;
                // ...
        }

        private void BtnSave_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                _someWritableOptions.Update(op => op.SomeField = someControl.Text);
        }
        // ...
}
```

**FormConfiguration.Designer.cs**

```
partial class FormConfiguration
{
        // Some Windows Forms stuff...
        this.btnSave.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.BtnSave_OnClick);
        // ...
}
```

The thing is I have both these classes (SomePresenter and FormConfiguration) and, after saving the changes in **SomePresenter**, *appsettings.json*'s *SomeField* value is indeed updated. But this does not happen whenever I try to do so inside the **FormConfiguration** class.

Any idea why?

Also, none of these two calls to IOptionsWritable.Update() throw an Exception.

Thanks in advance

**P.S.:** Sorry if the question is not clear enough. Don't mind letting me know if so!